# trouble with matplotlib's InsetPosition when having more than one subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm making this graph with 3 subplots where for each I want to have an inset axes, but with my code, it only creates the inset axes for the last subplot. Could you please help me with this. Thanks.

```
import pylab as pl
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import InsetPosition

def test(ax_main, pos, Data):
    ax2 = pl.axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
    ip = InsetPosition(ax_main, pos)
    ax2.set_axes_locator(ip)
    pl.hist(Data)

for i in range(3):
    ax=pl.subplot(1,3,i+1)
    Data = pl.rand(100)
    ax.plot(Data)
    test(ax, [.3,.3,.6,.6], Data)
```

[here is the result: (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmU8k.png)

**EDIT:**

I could work around this problem by using inset_axes:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.inset_locator import inset_axes
def test(ax_main, pos, Data):
    ax2 = inset_axes(ax_main, weight=pos[2], height=pos[3])  # weight and height are not important here because they will be changed in the next lines
    ip = InsetPosition(ax_main, pos)
    ax2.set_axes_locator(ip)
    pl.hist(Data)

for i in range(3):
    ax=pl.subplot(1,3,i+1)
    Data = pl.rand(100)
    ax.plot(Data)
    test(ax, [.3,.3,.6,.6], Data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here. The first one is understandable. As the [documentation of `figure.add_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes) says:

> If the figure already has an axes with the same parameters, then it will simply make that axes current and return it. This behavior has been deprecated as of Matplotlib 2.1. Meanwhile, if you do not want this behavior (i.e., you want to force the creation of a new Axes), you must use a unique set of args and kwargs. The axes label attribute has been exposed for this purpose: if you want two axes that are otherwise identical to be added to the figure, make sure you give them unique labels.

This means that if you call `plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1])` several times, it will not create a new axes after all. The solution would be to add a label, e.g. by supplying the loop variable i together with the data to the function and calling

```
plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1], label=str(i))
```

Unfortunately this is not enough and the above will still not work as expected. This is not understandable to me. However by trial and error one may find that using different coordinates for the initial position of the axes makes this work. Below I'm using `ax2 = plt.axes([0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1], label=str(i))`, but e.g. `[0.2, 0.0, 0.5, 0.1]` seems to work as well, while `[0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1]` does not work. Even more strange, `[0.0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1]` would create an inset in the second and third plot, but not in the first.

All of this seems a bit arbitrary, but sufficient for a solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import InsetPosition

def test(ax_main, pos, Data,i):
    ax2 = plt.axes([0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1], label=str(i))
    ip = InsetPosition(ax_main, pos)
    ax2.set_axes_locator(ip)
    ax2.plot(Data)


for i in range(3):
    ax=plt.subplot(1,3,i+1)
    test(ax, [.3,.3,.6,.6], [1,2], i)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I also saw this thread on the repository but didn't try installing the newer version of matplotlib: [https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9024](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9024)

Comment: I'm getting similar odd behavior from `from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes`. It works when calling a plotting function by itself, but when called by `pytest`, it causes the following test to fail. Inserting a `plt.close()` between the two tests solves the problem but I'm not sure if that's the best solution.